# Eliminating the action of babel from a given point onwards

Tags: babel

I'd like to use the Babel package to reproduce italian titles ONLY in the very first part of the document.

I'm writing my thesis and I'm expected to introduce the work by writing the title page (Titolo, Relatore...) and the abstract in italian (Sommario). 
The rest of my work is in english so, while I appreciate the effort of the babel package in the first part, I'd like to see it gone from the table of contents on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{\selectlanguage{british}\tableofcontents}` should work, I think — supposing the rest of your thesis is in British English.

Comment: @Bernard The problem os that I would like to remove the effect of babel from every point after the Abstract, so ToC, proofs, theorems, index...

Comment: Well, I suppose you want the default, i.e. english. Wouldn't writing `\selectlanguage{italian}\maketitle\begin{abstract}…\end{abstract}\selectlanguage{english}\titleofcontents …` work?